# How to read from a second file in same program?

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a game where I'm trying to make a top 5 high score board but the read function is not working properly. Here's the bubble sort algorithm I tried to implement:

```py
try:
    f = open("Highscores.txt", "r")
    f.flush()
    if f.read() == '':
        raise Exception('No data found in file!')
    f.seek(0)
    fList = []
    fList = fList.extend(f.readlines())
    
    print("Highscore list: ", fList)#db
    f.close()
    
    f = open("Highscores.txt", "w")
    
    x = 5
    for i in range(len(fList)):
        templist = []

        score = fList[i]
        justScore = score[score.find(" ")+1:]
        print(justScore)#db

        if int(justScore) > int(gw): #item in list compared to current user's score
            templist.append(f"{x}{score}")
        elif int(justScore) <= int(gw):
            templist.append(f"{x}{gameWinner}")
        else:
            templist.append(f"{x}{score}")
            
        x-=1
    print("Temporary list:"+templist)#db
    f.write('\n'.join(tempList))
    f.close()
except:
    print("\nolNo previous record of highscores")
    f = open("Highscores.txt", "w")
    
    f.write(f"1.{gameWinner}")
    f.write("does this work")
    print("file empty, first player")#db
    print(f"1.{gameWinner}")#db
    
    f.close()
```

This part doesn't seem to work

```
f.flush()
if f.read() == '':
    raise Exception('No data found in file!')
```

Full source code:

```py
#2 Player Card Game by Manpreet Singh
from random import shuffle

def deckMaker(colour, start=1,length=10):
    x = []
    for i in range(start,length+1):
        x.append(f"{colour} {i}")
    return x
#1-10 Item deck (array) maker.

def deckShuffler(deck):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(deck)): 
        x.extend(deck[i])
    shuffle(x)
    
    return x

def newLine(str1):
    x = str1.find("\n")
    if x != -1:
        return str1[:x]
    else:
        return str1
        
    
#Deck array is iterated into one large array 'x' then randomised with shuffle function.



deck = [deckMaker('Red'),deckMaker('Black'),deckMaker('Yellow')]
main_deck = deckShuffler(deck)
#30 card deck of red, black and yellow.



try:
    f = open('Card Game 1.0.txt', 'r')
    if f.read() == '':
        raise Exception('No data found in file!')
    #No data in file-detector.
    print("Authorise players.")
    
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e), e) #Error diagnostic
    
    f = open('Card Game 1.0.txt', 'w')
    print("No previous data in file, new players pick usernames!.")
    
    userOne = input("Player One: ")
    userOnePass = input("Password: ")
    f.write(userOne + "\n")
    f.write(userOnePass + "\n")
    
    userTwo = input("Player Two: ")
    userTwoPass = input("Password: ")
    f.write(userTwo + "\n")
    f.write(userTwoPass + "\n")

    f.close()
    #Writes 2 usernames to a file to be stored.
    print("Usernames saved, verify to continue")
    f = open('Card Game 1.0.txt', 'r')

    

#Error handling above to detect if file already exists and if it has data inside.

while True: 
    f.seek(0)
    fileList = []
    fileList.extend(f.readlines())
    #Makes list from file of usernames
    
    for i in range(len(fileList)):
        fileList[i] = newLine(fileList[i])
    #removes "\n" from all items
    
    usernames = fileList[::2]
    passwords = fileList[1::2]
    
    userOne = usernames[0]
    userTwo = usernames[1]
    
    passOne = passwords[0]
    passTwo = passwords[1]
    
    password1 = input(f"\n{userOne}\'s password: ")
    

    if password1 == passOne: 
        print("Player One verified!")
        password2 = input(f"\n{userTwo}\'s password: ")
        
        if password2 == passTwo:
            print("Player Two verified!")
            break
    else:
        print("Invalid, try again!")

print("Players verified, game continuing!")
#Authorises players - match usernames to previous players.


#Game Logic:
player_one_deck = []
player_two_deck = []
def gameLogic(onePick, twoPick, player_one_deck, player_two_deck, main_deck=main_deck):
    x = onePick.find(" ")
    y = twoPick.find(" ")
    
    oneColour = onePick[:x]
    twoColour = twoPick[:y]
    oneNum = onePick[x+1:]
    twoNum = twoPick[y+1:]
    
    bothPicks = [onePick, twoPick]

    
    #matchups:
    if oneColour == twoColour:
        
        if oneNum > twoNum:
            player_one_deck.extend(bothPicks)
            print(f"{userOne} wins that round and takes both cards!")
            
        elif twoNum > oneNum:
            player_two_deck.extend(bothPicks)
            print(f"{userTwo} wins that round and takes both cards!")

    else:
        if oneColour == 'Red' and twoColour == 'Black':
            player_one_deck.extend(bothPicks)
            print(f"{userOne} wins that round and takes both cards!")
        elif twoColour == 'Red' and oneColour == 'Black':
            player_two_deck.extend(bothPicks)
            print(f"{userTwo} wins that round and takes both cards!")
            
        if oneColour == 'Yellow' and twoColour == 'Red':
            player_one_deck.extend(bothPicks)
            print(f"{userOne} wins that round and takes both cards!")
        elif twoColour == 'Yellow' and oneColour == 'Red':
            player_two_deck.extend(bothPicks)
            print(f"{userTwo} wins that round and takes both cards!")
            
        if oneColour == 'Black' and twoColour == 'Yellow':
            player_one_deck.extend(bothPicks)
            print(f"{userOne} wins that round and takes both cards!")
        elif twoColour == 'Black' and oneColour == 'Yellow':
            player_two_deck.extend(bothPicks)
            print(f"{userTwo} wins that round and takes both cards!")
            
    main_deck.remove(onePick)
    main_deck.remove(twoPick)
    

x=0
while True:
    try:
        firstPick = main_deck[0]
        secondPick = main_deck[1]
    except IndexError:
        break
    #Error handling - occurs when main deck has no more cards left.
    
    input(f"\nPress ENTER to start round {x}!")
    x+=1
    
    
    print(f"{userOne} has drawn {firstPick}!")
    print(f"{userTwo} has drawn {secondPick}!")
    
    gameLogic(firstPick, secondPick, player_one_deck, player_two_deck)

print("\n")

def winnerOutput(player, playerDeck):
    print(f"{player} WINS THE WHOLE GAME!")
    print("Amount of Cards:", len(playerDeck))
    
    return [player, len(playerDeck)]

winner = 0
if len(player_one_deck) > len(player_two_deck):
    wDetails = winnerOutput(userOne, player_one_deck)
elif len(player_two_deck) > len(player_one_deck):
    wDetails = winnerOutput(userTwo, player_two_deck)
else:
    print("DRAW!!!")
    print("Initialising world ending sequence...")

f.close()

print(wDetails)#db
winner = wDetails[0]
winnerDeck = wDetails[1]

    
gameWinner = f"{winner} {winnerDeck}"
gw = gameWinner[gameWinner.find(" ")+1:]


try:
    f = open("Highscores.txt", "r")
    f.flush()
    if f.read() == '':
        raise Exception('No data found in file!')
    f.seek(0)
    fList = []
    fList = fList.extend(f.readlines())
    
    print("Highscore list: ", fList)#db
    f.close()
    
    f = open("Highscores.txt", "w")
    
    x = 5
    for i in range(len(fList)):
        templist = []

        score = fList[i]
        justScore = score[score.find(" ")+1:]
        print(justScore)#db

        if int(justScore) > int(gw): #item in list compared to current user's score
            templist.append(f"{x}{score}")
        elif int(justScore) <= int(gw):
            templist.append(f"{x}{gameWinner}")
        else:
            templist.append(f"{x}{score}")
            
        x-=1
    print("Temporary list:"+templist)#db
    f.write('\n'.join(tempList))
    f.close()
except:
    print("\nolNo previous record of highscores")
    f = open("Highscores.txt", "w")
    
    f.write(f"1.{gameWinner}")
    f.write("does this work")
    print("file empty, first player")#db
    print(f"1.{gameWinner}")#db
    
    f.close()
```

Comment: (1) you can read from a second file by using `open(filename, 'r')` a second time, but what does that have to do with the rest of your post? (2) what do you mean by "this part doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: You should never `except:`, this will catch every exception thrown, instead, try excepting a single error. It is also more explicit as to what you want to do this way.

Comment: @mkrieger1 whenever I do if `if f.read() == '':` it always comes out as positive despite there being data in the file, so i have come to the conclusion it is not reading properly.

Comment: @xihtyM can I raise an exception from an if statement, if so how.

Comment: @ManpreetSingh if you want to catch the exception thrown, either write `except Exception` instead (this will not `BaseException`, or the system-exiting exceptions). Or (I would recommend) take a different approach to coding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### I think you are meant to ask, "How to read from a file, twice?"

The structure of your program is unwise. Do not rely on exceptions to pick up normal events, such as no file yet existing.

#### Preparation

```
import os
import json

HI_SCORE_FILENAME = "hiscores.txt"
```

#### Function to update

```
import os
import json

HI_SCORE_FILENAME = "hiscores.txt"

def update_high_scores(name,score):

    high_scores = []
    if os.path.exists(HI_SCORE_FILENAME):
        with open(HI_SCORE_FILENAME,"rt") as f:
            high_scores = json.load(f)
    
    high_scores.append( [name,score] )
    high_scores.sort(key=lambda name_and_score:-name_and_score[1] ) 

    with open(HI_SCORE_FILENAME,"wt") as f:
            json.dump(high_scores,f)
```

#### Example of use

```
update_high_scores("Bob",10)
update_high_scores("Jane",1000)
update_high_scores("Sam",500)
```

#### Result:

```
[
  ["Jane", 1000], 
  ["Sam", 500], 
  ["Bob", 10]
]
```

Comment: You're actually proposing worse way to handle the check. `os.path.exists` and `open` are not atomic in your example. It's better to handle exception when possible.

Comment: I agree, in a race condition of two copies of the program fighting, you could get into a mess. But the original version was confusing the OP, even with a single instance of the program. 8-)   I quite agree that on top of what I showed, it would be good to handle exceptions, but they would be for truly exceptional circumstances, like someone cheekily adding/deleting files while the program runs, or lack of write permissions, etc.